# Getting NameError for annotation even if I use TYPE_CHECKING import

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I have two classes with annotations / type hints.

First one works without any problem:

```python
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from bunyamin.models.exchange import Exchange

class Kline:

    def read_klines(exchange: Exchange):
        pass
```

Second one is really similar:

```python
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from bunyamin.models.timeframe import Timeframe

def normalize_dt(dt: datetime, timeframe: Timeframe) -> datetime:  # -> This line raises NameError
    pass
```

but raises `NameError: name 'Timeframe' is not defined`.

I know I can just use a string (like `'Timeframe'`) instead of the class itself, but AFAIK this is not the expected behavior. What am I missing?

Python version I'm using is 3.8.2, if that's relevant.

**EDIT:**

While I was trying to isolate the problem, I've omitted all of the "*seemingly* irrelevant" imports. But the first file actually contains `from __future__ import annotations` at the top, which makes it work. See the first answer for details.

Comment: Just ran a test on my end, and calling `TYPE_CHECKING` returns `FALSE`. You may want to check using the debugger or a print statement to check that you're actually entering that first `if` statement. Not sure why it works in the first but not the second, but that's what I found on my end.

Comment: Well it returns false no matter where you use it, because as of it's nature, it's always `FALSE` at runtime. 

See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html
which states: 

The TYPE_CHECKING constant defined by the typing module is False at runtime but True while type checking.


I've found the solution elsewhere.

Comment: It's strange that your first example works, it shouldn't work

Comment: Yes, exactly. It does not work the way I've put it there. Actual file contains `from __future__ import annotations`, as now explained in both in the answer and the edited question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it.

For isolating the problem, I've omitted the "seemingly" irrelevant imports on both classes. But I've just noticed that in the first file which contains `Kline` class, I've used `from __future__ import annotations` and in the second I did not, which postpones the evaluation of the annotations.

Reference can be found here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/

Note that `from __future__ import annotations` has to occur at the top of the file, or it raises a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Yes, this import enables so called postponed evaluation of annotations, that will become default since Python 3.10.

Comment: +1: Not sure why the other answer received more upvotes: postponing annotations is a nicer solution than forward referencing with a whole bunch of quotes.

Comment: @alex_noname `from __future__ import annotations` is still not default in Python 3.12 and there is no timeline on when it will become default.

Answer (score 13):

When you use `TYPE_CHECKING` constant, function parameters annotations must be enclosed in quotes, making it a “forward reference”, to hide it from the interpreter at runtime, as `timeframe: 'Timeframe'`. Because these are evaluates at a time of function definition by default until Python 3.10, when postponed evaluation of annotation becomes the default.

Comment: I already know that I can enclose it in quotes (as original question states), but my original question was why it is working in the first example but not in the second one, which I've just resolved a few minutes ago (see the first answer)

Comment: Even though this isn't directly answering the question it helped me with what I needed. Thanks.